# How to get the length of of huffman codes

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, huffman-code

I am trying to find the length of code generated on Huffman encoding for finding Huffman compression efficiency:

My code for Huffman encoding is:

Function call is `GenerateCode(rear, "",Obj);` These Obj is used for internal purpose(you may feel it un-necessary but i am using it to have the data in current context).

```
    public void GenerateCode(Node parentNode, string code, MainPage obj)
    {
        obj.listBox2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (parentNode != null)
        {
            GenerateCode(parentNode.left, code + "0",obj);
            if (parentNode.left == null && parentNode.right == null)
               obj.listBox2.Items.Add("Symbol :" + parentNode.symbol + " - " + "Code : " + code);
               GenerateCode(parentNode.right, code + "1",obj);
        }
    }
```

And suppose Huffman Table obtained is this :

```
symbol : 0 Code : 1
symbol : 1 Code : 00
symbol : 2 Code : 011
symbol : 3 Code : 010
```

Now i am not able to **find the logic in c#** to calculate the length on these encoding corresponding to each symbols so that i would be able to multiply them with frequency to calculate the Huffman compression efficiency.  Because they are string of "0 and 1" so how to calculate the length from them ?

Comment: Didn't the answers to your previous question answer that? It looked to me as though they did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length will be `code.Length`, length in bytes will be `(float)code.Length / 8`. Important is to compare with original length in the same units, bits or bytes.